# I need help with this interest rate thing

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question asks: "You deposit $425 into a money market account for three months. The account earns 2.5% simple interest. How much money is in the account after three months? Round your answer to the nearest cent."

Comment: What book are you using? Also, at what rate is the interest compounded?

Comment: Practice workbook, CA

Comment: @alvonellos It's Simple Interest right, mentioned there **2.5% simple Interest**

Comment: Whoops, haha. I'll leave the answer to you, then.

Comment: Yup! I think so.

Comment: Is it $2.5$% *per annum*?

Answer (score 1):

The Formula used to calculate **amount** for Simple Interest is:

$$SI = \frac{P\times R\times T}{100}$$

where,

SI = Interest gained in time T

T = Time duration for which the Interest is being Calculated (in yrs.)

R = Rate of Interest

So, here P = $\$425$, T = 3 months (ie $\frac{3}{12} $ yrs), R = 2.5

$$SI = \frac{425\times3\times2.5}{12\times100} $$
Now the amount after 3 months will be,

$$Amount(A) = Principal(P) + Simple Interest(SI)$$

Now the calculation is easy. Hope you get it @IcyAlice.